# ES6 reduce array without typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

i want to remove the first array element, without modified the original (immutable),
something like this:

```
function getArray(): number[] {
   return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}
function getAnother(): number[] {
   const [first, ...rest] = getArray();
   return rest;
}
```

the code works, but the typescript check complained:

```
'first' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Is there the elegant/better way to do somilar to `getAnother()`?

Comment: `arr.slice(1)`?

Comment: Also, it's not the typescript check that complains, this is an ESLint rule. As with literally any ESLint rule, you can adjust it or disable it (even locally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore an element with a comma.

```
 const [, ...rest] = getArray();
```

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) can also be used in this case.

```
const rest = getArray().slice(1);
```

Comment: @HeyyyMarco Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default Array method

```
Array.prototype.slice
```

Try this

```
function getAnother(): number[] {
    return getArray().slice(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One common practice here is to *prefix unused variables or arguments with an underscore*, as in one of the following:

```js
const [_first, ...rest] = getArray();
const [_, ...rest] = getArray();
```

This allows you to still use a visible or labeled placeholder. Though this works without configuration in Visual Studio Code's syntax highlighting, you may need to configure it for your ESLint usage with [`varsIgnorePattern` and `argsIgnorePattern`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/4ca58886adf3fc0fe31c263559990c8a534205f9/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/no-unused-vars.ts#L14-L20), which in ESLint [is suggested in documentation as `"^_"`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern).